# How to diagonalize a single particle hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian

$$H=\hbar\omega \left(a^\dagger a+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\hbar \omega_0\left(a^\dagger+a\right)$$ How to diagonalize $H$ and find its eigenenergies?

Comment: What are your attempts, what have you tried?

Comment: I am very clueless could you give me a hint

Comment: you can take a look at this at the section "Matrix representation": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using creation and annihilation operators is a bit misleading here, since the problem is much easier to solve in ordinary notation. Note that
$$
x=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\left(a+a^{\dagger}\right) \ ,
$$
so your Hamiltonian can be rewritten as
$$
H=\frac{1}{2m}p^2+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x^2+\eta x
$$
for $\eta=\hbar\omega_0\sqrt{2m\omega/\hbar}$. Now you only need to complete the square to obtain a harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian with a shifted center and a constant term:
$$
H=\frac{1}{2m}p^2+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}\left(x+\frac{\eta}{m\omega^2}\right)^2
-\frac{\eta^2}{2m\omega^2}.
$$
This Hamiltonian has the usual eigenvalues, with a constant subtracted:
$$
E_n=\hbar\omega\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{\eta^2}{2m\omega^2}
=\hbar\omega\left(n+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\omega_0^2}{\omega^2}\right)
 \ ,
$$
for $n=0,1,2,...$.

Comment: Nice solution! Would it be possible to solve this by writing the matrix representation of $H$ on the Fock basis?

Comment: @Matteo I'm not sure. Due to the properties of $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$, we will have a tridiagonal matrix of the form $H_{kl}=k\delta_{kl}+q(\sqrt{k}\delta_{k,l+1}+\sqrt{l}\delta_{l,k+1})$ (I subtracted the $1/2$ term of the ZPE, and turned to $\hbar\omega$ units; $q=\omega_0/\omega$). However, I don't see any straightforward way to diagonalize it. I'll have to think about this... (Of course, it is easy to check numerically that the eigenvalues do tend to $k-q^2$ as the basis size is increased.)

Comment: You can also complete the square with the ladder operators. More generally, note that the Hamiltonian is up to a constant shift unitarily equivalent to the harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian, where the unitary operator is just the translation operator.

Comment: @dennismoore94 I asked about this on mathematics stack exchange, if you are interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731225/diagonalization-of-specific-symmetric-tridiagonal-matrix